# How can I get UTF-8 text in action class when starting server in Struts 2?

Tags: java, jsp, utf-8, struts2, character-encoding

I'm developing a web application by Struts 2 using Hibernate.

But I have a problem that When I start server and load website then my loading method in action will be called. But, It can't load UTF-8, instead of `"Phương"` I get `"PH??NG"` But in JSP page still display `"Phương"`. So that, when I execute my SQL query and it is (`from Posts WHERE topics like '%PH??NG PHÁP GIÁO D?C TR?%'`, so I cannot query to my database.

My action class here:

```
public class PostsAction extends ActionSupport {
private List<HomeTopic> homeTopics = new ArrayList<HomeTopic>();
public List<HomeTopic> getHomeTopics() {
    return homeTopics;
}

public void setHomeTopics(List<HomeTopic> homeTopics) {
    this.homeTopics = homeTopics;
}


public void callHomeTopics(){
     Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction trans = session.beginTransaction();
    String[] list = {"NEW – TIN TỨC TRẺ","Khu Vui Chơi Cho Trẻ","PHƯƠNG PHÁP GIÁO DỤC TRẺ","KỸ NĂNG – KINH NGHIỆM","Phòng Bệnh","Tập Tô Màu"};
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            getTopics(session, trans, list[i]);
        }
trans.commit();
    session.close();
}

public void getTopics(Session session, Transaction trans, String type) {
    String hql = "from Posts WHERE topics like '%" + type + "%'";
    System.out.println("HQL: " + hql);
    Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
    query.setMaxResults(3);
    List<Posts> t = (ArrayList<Posts>) query.list();
    HomeTopic h = new HomeTopic(type, t);
    System.out.println("List topics: " + type + " " + t);
    homeTopics.add(h);
    session.flush();
}
```

**`HomeTopics.java` class:**

```
 public class HomeTopic {

    private String nameTopic;
    private List<Posts> postList;

    public List<Posts> getPostList() {
        return postList;
    }

    public void setPostList(List<Posts> postList) {
        this.postList = postList;
    }

    public HomeTopic(String nameTopic, List<Posts> postList) {
        this.nameTopic = nameTopic;
        this.postList = postList;
    }

    public HomeTopic() {
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "HomeTopic{" + "nameTopic=" + nameTopic + ", postList=" + postList + '}';
    }

    public String getNameTopic() {
        return nameTopic;
    }

    public void setNameTopic(String nameTopic) {
        this.nameTopic = nameTopic;
    }
}
```

When I write main method to test It still display UTF-8. But whenever I start server and call `callHomeTopics()` method in browser the text will is `"PH??NG PHÁP GIÁO D?C TR?"`.

But in JSP page still display `"Phương Pháp Giáo Dục Trẻ"`.
Everything ok except my HQL query.

Comment: Do you get the correct results from database?

Comment: Do you mean that the `System.out`s are printing the wrong characters in your IDE or Server console ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are (for testing purposes, I suppose) hard-coding your values, instead of reading them from a database or a web page, you need to ensure that the IDE you are using to insert them in the page is working in `UTF-8`;

In Eclipse, go to <kbd>Window</kbd> -> <kbd>Preferences</kbd> -> <kbd>General</kbd> -> <kbd>Workspace</kbd> -> <kbd>Text file encoding</kbd> -> <kbd>Other</kbd> -> <kbd>UTF-8</kbd>.

This is needed to see the correct values while printing out to console too.

When you will read the values from JSP or database instead, pay attention to the character encoding, and ensure to use

```
byte[] utf8Bytes = myString.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

for encoding, and

```
String myString = new String(utf8Bytes, "UTF-8")
```

for decoding.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/string.html

Comment: Your first part is ok, but the code is so horribly wrong I cannot not downvote. Your code will do absolutely nothing while thinking it does - that is dangerous... Even on the page you linked the variable that this is done on is called `roundTrip`.

Comment: Then it should be +1 for first part, and -1 for the second one :D Being serious, I don't understand you: they're clearly two different pieces of code, don't get fooled by the unique code format block :/

Comment: Ok I see now... the code used in a row (round-tripping) is not uncommon even though it does nothing useful, so I assumed you were making the same mistake as well. I have edited it to make more clear and it deserves a +1 now :)

Comment: Yeah, probably my mistake for not being completely clear ;) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To display characters correctly to corresponding encoding in the JSP you should use the  JSP `page` directive and specify the `contentType` with encoding. For example

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
```

this will display characters on the page with UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: In jsp page still display UTF-8!

Comment: JSP is a java *server* page, not is what displayed in your editor.

Answer (score -1):

use the corresponding utf code for your french characters rather than using them directly.
For example

```
use &#233; for é
```

hope this helps